# MySql Event ( adding +1 online time if user is online )

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I tried to create this MySQL event.
My code:

```
    delimiter |

CREATE EVENT `add_time`
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 SECOND
    COMMENT 'Adding 1 second to online time'
    DO
      BEGIN
        UPDATE `users` SET `OnlineTime`=`OnlineTime`+1 WHERE 1;
      END |

delimiter ;
```

Now, this isn't working :/. I'm new Mysql user and I don't know how to loop, if(), get column data in variable ect.
What I wanna do is:

Add `OnlineTime` to every `user` where `OnlineTime` is < 5000sec, if `OnlineTime` is >= 5000sec I want to delete that user.

Comment: All Users in the table?  Can a user go away and come back?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, record the start time of the user.  The EVENT would not increment a timer, instead it would subtract to see if the time limit has been exceeded.